# Multi-tenancy in Spring JDBC with Different Source and Destination DBs

Tags: java, spring, multi-tenant

I plan on to implement multi-tenancy in Spring JDBC application, with a different DB for reading and a different DB for writing. Here`s what I have done so far:

- Created a thread local object to hold current tenant
- Extended AbstractRoutingDataSource class from Spring JDBC, which holds the current look up key, I am returning the key as tenant + "source/target".
- I have DB configuration set that holds tenant like: If a tenant is named "x", I store "xsource" -> Source DB Config, "xtarget" -> target DB config
- Then on entry and exit of method boundaries, I have tampered the tenant by appending "source" and "target". Something like following for step A:

TenantManager is the threadlocal.

```
public method foo(){
    tenantManager.setTenant(tenantManager.getTenant() + "source");
    //Application Logic goes here
    tenantManager.setTenant(tenantManager.getTenant().replace("source", ""));
}
```

And then for other step:

```
public method bar(){
    tenantManager.setTenant(tenantManager.getTenant() + "target");
    //Application Logic goes here
    tenantManager.setTenant(tenantManager.getTenant().replace("target", ""));
}
```

The above approach creates a lot of confusion, and I am not sure whether this might hold well while debugging or not, please advise how should I manage such situation as I believe there must be a better way to handle this.

Comment: Wait. You are defying the whole concept of data consistency here? Why do you even need this use-case? The Read DB will keep returning stale data

Comment: The read DB is a realtime updating data, which is bound to update every 6 hours or so, moving the read DB is not possible since it is an external source to my application which is populated by an job.

Comment: Ok. And multi-tenancy is at schema level right? I think you can achieve this without manipulating tenant - by performing the read and write in separate threads. After read operation, submit the task of writing to a future (with tenant info). Now in the future runnable/callable, just set the AbstractRoutingDataSource lookup key to point to "write" DB and set the tenant context

Comment: With manipulating tenant, you may face issues, if you have some centralized logging configured and want to trace logs for a given tenant

Comment: Yeap, I am too not in favor of manipulating tenant. My code takes in a job in this format
```
stepBuilderFactory.get(<MY_STEP>).<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .reader(ReaderImpl).writer(WriterImpl)....build();
```
You mean to alter the writerimpl?

Comment: Yeah. I can help you out if you share some actual implementation. You can use this site to paste and send some code snippets: https://friendpaste.com/

Comment: https://friendpaste.com/6ppeO6IeXz2lr4D55PRjKC